# d3: Adding and removing force.nodes based on slider values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had some difficulty a while back adding and removing nodes based on user input which was solved by updating the entire set of objects pushed into force.nodes() each time the user selected which they wanted to view from a list of checkboxes.

Updating from a slider however I think requires a more finesse touch - I don't want to update the entire set every time the slider is moved. I want to push and pop nodes in and out of force.nodes().

With my current code the nodes are coming out just fine - they're just not going back in. jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/ancmtxux/3/

This is the part causing problems;

```
function brushed() {
    var exists;

    //var newd = new Date(2013, 05, 01)

    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        //if data point in range (between extent 0 and 1)
        if (d.date >= brush.extent()[0] && d.date <= brush.extent()[1]) {
            exists = force.nodes().some(function(node, i) {
                //check if data point already exists in force.nodes()
                return (node.mIndex == d.mIndex)                
                })
            console.log(exists)
            if (!exists) {
                force.nodes().push(d)
            }
        }
        else {
            force.nodes().splice(i, 1)
        }   
    })



    d3.select("#nodeCount").text(force.nodes().length)
}
```

For each data point, I'm checking whether or not the point lies between extent()[0] and [1]. If it does, then check force.nodes() to see if it's currently a member there. If it isn't, then push it into force.nodes().

If the data point doesn't lie between the extents then splice it from force.nodes(). This last bit works just fine.

UPDATE: Fixed. I actually also worked out how to filter links attached to nodes as well. jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/7oumeat5/2/. Never try and do this with indexes/hard coded indexes, compare  the nodes/links as objects.

Incidentally I'm seeing links over the top of nodes. If there's some way to fix this I'd be happy to hear it.

FURTHER UPDATE: To ensure links behind nodes use .insert("line", ":first-child") in place of .append("line")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current code. The fundamental problem is that you're giving `data` to `force.nodes()`, which means that the two data structures are actually the same. That is, when you're removing elements from `force.nodes()`, you're modifying the underlying `data` as well. Hence you can't add them back -- they're gone.

This is easily fixed by passing a copy of `data` to `force.nodes()`:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

Then you're removing the wrong nodes from `force.nodes()` -- the index you're using is for `data`, not `force.nodes()`. You can compute the index of the `data` element in `force.nodes()` and use it like this:

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        var idx = -1;
        force.nodes().forEach(function(node, j) {
            if(node.mIndex == d.mIndex) {
                idx = j;
            }
        });
        //if data point in range (between extent 0 and 1)
        if (d.date >= brush.extent()[0] && d.date <= brush.extent()[1]) {
            if (idx == -1) {
                force.nodes().push(d)
            }
        }
        else if(idx > -1) {
            force.nodes().splice(idx, 1)
        }
```

Finally, you need to call `force.start()` at the end of `brushed` for the changes to become visible after the layout has settled down.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ancmtxux/5/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77339/discussion-on-answer-by-lars-kotthoff-d3-adding-and-removing-force-nodes-based).

Comment: I've tried to avoid using those. I'm using the computer indexes to get rid of the links but only after finding the indexes via matcing up source and links with the associatedLinks source and links. I'm even reinserting nodes and links to their resp. original positions via splice() so I've tried to negate that at every turn. The codes conviluted though so it's hard to follow where I'm going wrong. Will try a different strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from the mighty @Lars Kotthoff, who fixed your technical problem, I will focus on the architecture.  Here is an architecture that is simpler and more in keeping with d3 idiom.

The main principles are:

1. Use `Array.prototype.filter()` to manage the data
2. Use standard, data driven patterns.
   Drive the visualisation by managing the data and then use the standard, general update pattern to drive the changes into the vis.
3. Seperate data events and animation events.
   Respond to the data changes only when need... do it in the brushed event, not on every tick.  The `brushed` event is a *data event* and the `tick` routine is an *animation event*.  It's not optimal to be managing data on animation events on the off chance that it is required.
4. Make the entry and exit of the nodes a bit smoother.

The benefit of point 1 is that the filtered array is actually an array of reference to the original `data` elements, so when the extra state is added on the copied array, it is actually added on the original `data` array.  Thus, the previous state is available when it is filtered back in, hence the smooth exit and entry behaviour.  Meanwhile, no elements are deleted in the original `data` when the brush filters down: only the references to them are deleted in the cloned array.  I have to admit I had not expected that but it is a nice discovery, even if by accident!
Of course this only works because the array elements are objects.

working example here...

```js
var width = 700,
    height = 600,
    padding = 20;

    var start = new Date(2013, 0, 1),
      end = new Date(2013, 11, 31)

    var data = []

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var point = {}

      var year = 2013;
      var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)
      var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28)

      point.date = new Date(year, month, day)
      point.mIndex = i
      data.push(point)
    }

    var force = d3.layout.force()
          .size([width - padding, height - 100])
          .on("tick", tick)
          .start()

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height
      })

    //build stuff
    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain([start, end])
      .range([padding, width - 6 * padding])
      .clamp(true)

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(20)
    //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%x"))

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x)
      .extent([start, end])
      .on("brush", brushed1)

    //append stuff
    var slidercontainer = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(100, 500)")

    var axis = slidercontainer.append("g")
      .call(xAxis)

    var slider = slidercontainer.append("g")
      .call(brush)
      .classed("slider", true)

    //manipulate stuff
    d3.selectAll(".resize").append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", "Red")
      .classed("handle", true)

    d3.select(".domain")
      .select(function () { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)) })
      .classed("halo", true)

    function brushed1(e) {

      var nodes = includedNodes(data, brush);

        nodes.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .call(force.drag)
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })

      nodes
        .exit()
        .remove()

      force
        .nodes(includedData(data, brush))
        .start()

    }

    function includedData(data, brush) {

      return data.filter(function (d, i, a) {
        return d.date >= brush.extent()[0] && d.date <= brush.extent()[1]
      })

    }
    function includedNodes(data, brush) {
      return svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(includedData(data, brush), function (d, i) {
                return d.mIndex
              })
    }

    function tick() {

      includedNodes(data, brush)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })

    }
    brushed1()
```

```css
.domain {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: .3;
      stroke-width: 10px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .halo {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ddd;
      stroke-width: 8px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .tick {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .selecting circle {
      fill-opacity: .2;
    }

      .selecting circle.selected {
        stroke: #f00;
      }

    .handle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: .5;
      stroke-width: 1.25px;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<p id="nodeCount"></p>
```

Comment: @hwilson1 given the problems your having with your original structure, which was salvaged by Lars, I'm wondering if you had a look at this. Just run the snippet.

Comment: my intention is to get stuck in to your example once I've conquered adding/removing nodes. Your example adds in a couple of elegent flourishes that would just be more work for me to understand at this stage. I've come up with another example which gets rid of the slider and replaces it with checkboxes so I can clearly see what's happening with node indexes (each cb assigned to each index etc). jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/296g1vt2/. I'm very close to having it worked out, current problem however is links sitting on top of nodes. For no reason I can see. Any advice?

Comment: I figured out adding/removing nodes. Now struggling with adding/removing associated links. I've put up a jsfiddle here - jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/r9135qmp/1 - I've output some data about what's going on with the four nodes or links. The first and third columns are force.nodes()/force.links(), the 2nd and 4th columns are nodedata and linkdata. Using the slider should pop notes in and out but it regularly breaks, I think because the indexes aren't matching up correctly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @hwilson1 your fiddle works on the first brush, then breaks.  Like I said, it's great to fix technical details but your architecture is flawed. The method I showed is not fancy, it's just constrained to use standard patterns but deployed for this special situation. You really should consider it ;)

Comment: I think the fiddle in the update to the question should be working? There's a few niggles I think as a consequence of duplicate links due to the way I'm generating nodes/links randomly (investigating this) but is 99% there. Day off today, then I'll get cracking with your way tomorrow :) Looks a lot more streamlined.