# How to compute and store a graph and all its modifications with networkx (and d3js)?

Tags: python, json, networkx

I'm trying to represent a dataset composed of various related items in the form of a simple, undirected relationship graph of this form:

[image: Simple graph (D3JS force-directed graph)]

The dataset is originally presented as a log file, with for each log line a copy of one of the items after modification. This includes attributes of the item as well as other items with which it is related.

Here is a basic example:

```
logs = {
    "item_1": {
        "color": "blue",
        "relatives": []
    },
    "item_2": {
        "color": "green",
        "relatives": []
    },
    "item_1": {
        "color": "blue",
        "relatives": ["object_1"]
    },
    "item_1": {
        "color": "red",
        "relatives": []
    }
}
```

(If it's useful, the logs are initially in the form of a complex XML that I transform into a dictionary with [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict))

Here, the third log represents the creation of a link between item 1 and 2, and the fourth log represents the deletion of this same link (in addition to changing an attribute of item 1).

Represented as a graph, it is therefore a matter of adding a blue "1" node, then adding a green "2" node, then connecting the two, then removing the edge between items 1 and 2 and changing the color of node "1".

Currently, I can create the graph with a code resembling this one:

```
for log in logs.items():

    # Adding the object (if non existant) or updating it
    G.add_node(log[0], color=log[1].get("color", "black"))

    # Edges creation
    if "relatives" in log[1]:
        for rel in relatives:
            G.add_edge(log[0], rel)
```

My problems are as follows:

### How to properly manage the case of relationship deletions?

My code allows you to populate the graph with new nodes and links, and update the attributes as they change, but I don't know how to detect deletion of links.

I wanted to see if calculating a diff could help me, using the [jsondiff](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff) library. I get, with the explicit jsondiff syntax, logs of the following form:

```
{UPDATE: {"color":"red","relative": {DELETE:[0]}}}}}
```

However, this requires keeping in memory the current status of all objects to know which link in the graph corresponds to the 0-th element to delete. So I'm thinking of passing an object containing the list of items related to networkx as node (instead of the label alone). Is there a better way to do it?

### How do I access the graph as it is built after a given log line?

That's my main problem. I need to be able to see the status of the graph at any time (i. e. after any selected log line). What is the way to store the graph that allows me to do this correctly? Naively, having a graph for every moment, but it quickly becomes absurdly heavy (my example dataset has several thousand logs, and I have to be able to handle much bigger ones). Perhaps by putting the lifetime of a link in its attributes, and using it as a condition to show or not the edge?

An ideal solution would be to display an animation with d3.js that visually represents the evolution of the dataset.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very inspiring, is it?

I continued to think about my problem, and came to the following solution, which answers both problems (both managing the disappearance of links and storing the evolution of the graph over time): write a date of birth and death in each link.

So I get, after processing the log files, a list of quadruplets `(i, r, b, d)` each representing a link between an item `i` and a second related item `r`, which appears in the graph at date `b` and disappears at date `d`.

I discovered that this way of representing the evolution of a graph is called *Link Stream* : [Clémence Magnien's lecture (French)](http://sms.univ-tlse2.fr/servlet/com.univ.collaboratif.utils.LectureFichiergw?ID_FICHIER=1317125412889), and [Tiphaine Viard's Thesis](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01521029/document) talk about it.

As for the animated visualization with d3.js, I found a fairly close answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063354/d3-adding-and-removing-force-nodes-based-on-slider-values), with notably an example of d3.js code having the desired result, which I will only have to adapt to take into account the birth and death attributes of the links.